# "refresh_tasks cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I basically copy & pasted the code from right above and replaced the necessary tidbits, yet I still get this error. I'm trying to make a "Refresh" item in my menu.

XML code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <item
      android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:orderInCategory="100"
      android:showAsAction="never"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

  <item
      android:id="@+id/refresh_tasks"
      android:title="@string/refresh"/>

</menu>
```

HomeActivity.java code:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.refresh_tasks: //line where I get error
            loadTasksFromAPI(TASKS_URL);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I've searched across the internet, but I haven't managed to fix this. I assume something is wrong with my XML, but I don't see what it could be.

Comment: Check your import statement to make sure that you imported application's R not of Android.

Comment: Yup, I imported my application's R.

Comment: And are you able to access `action_settings`??

Comment: Yeah, I'm able to access that.

Answer (score 1):

So, apparently my R.java stopped updating for some reason. My code was correct, but it wouldn't update. Editing the AndroidManifest.xml file and then saving seems to force R.java into updating. It's as simple as adding a space and then deleting the space from your AndroidManifest.xml file before you save (though, you could leave the space if you wish... It shouldn't cause an error).

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure there are no errors in any of your resources
  . This would cause AAPT to stop generating a new R.class for you
- Clean and rebuild the project

EDIT: Try to add this at the beginning of the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Comment: `R.java` is not built unless I delete the xml code for my 'refresh_tasks' item. The refresh_tasks item does not trigger an error though.

Comment: Yeah, I'm very perplexed by this. Perhaps it shouldn't be an item? This is very new to me.

Comment: Please try what I have suggested in my edited answer.

Comment: Above `<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >`? If so, that didn't work.

Comment: Okay, leave it there nevertheless, it's needed to make it a valid xml.

Comment: I just used the graphical interface to create the 'refresh_tashs' element and it still doesn't detect it...

Comment: Try to restart your IDE.

Comment: Also check the IDE console and make sure there is no error in another place.

Comment: I just posted the answer, but in essence my R.java just wouldn't update for some reason, so I had to force it into an update.